# Case code in Ruby program not working with a passed value

Tags: ruby, arguments, case, procedure

Have written some test code for a program, trying to pass 2 values, a file and a number. The below doesn't work at all, but if I have something like `puts "test"`  (outside the case) it works.

```
def read_album(music_file, number)
    puts number #(this does something)
    case number.to_i
    when(number > 1)
            puts "done"
    when(number < 2)
            puts "something"
    when(number == 3)
        puts "none of this inside case is working"
    end
end

def main()
    a_file = File.new("albums.txt", "r")
    print("Choose album id: ")
    choice_of_album = gets().to_i
    read_album(a_file, choice_of_album)
end

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the `number.to_i` from the case statement.

Or do something like

```
case number.to_i
    when 1..2 
        puts "foo"
    when 3..100
        puts "bar"
    else 
        puts "foobar"
    end
end
```

From the Ruby docs

> Case statements consist of an optional condition, which is in the position of an argument to case, and zero or more when clauses. The first when clause to match the condition (or to evaluate to Boolean truth, if the condition is null) “wins”, and its code stanza is executed. The value of the case statement is the value of the successful when clause, or nil if there is no such clause.

Your version would evaluate to somehting like

```
if (number > 1) === number.to_i
```

and since you are comparing a number with a boolean expression this will not evaluate to true. If you had an else in the case statement this would have been called.

Comment: Actually it would evaluate to `(number > 1) === number.to_i`

Comment: ah thanks, fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Your `case`s are not doing what you think. The expressions given to `when` are evaluated and the result will be compared to the `case` value using the case equality operator `===`. An expression such as `number > 1` will evaluate to either `true` or `false`. It makes no sense to compare this result to an integer in Ruby.

You should compare against the constants directly.

```
case number
when 1
  # handle 1
when 2
  # handle 2
when 3
  # handle 3
else
  # handle unknown case; error?
end
```

Note that other classes may override `===` to provide useful behavior. The `Range` and `Regexp` classes, for example, do this.

```
case number
when 1..3
  # handle 1, 2 and 3
end

case string
when /pattern/
  # handle pattern
end
```

Notably, the `Proc` class also does this!

```
def greater_than(n)
  proc { |x| x > n }
end

case number
when greater_than(2)
  # handle number > 2
end
```